# Installing two identical breakers in Parallel for very basic redundancy

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a question about an issue that has been discussed in this forum, but with slightly different parameters.  I completely understand that installing two smaller breakers in parallel instead of one large one is a NO GO, but in my setup things are very different.  I have a maximum load of 66 Amp @ 240 Volt split phase (Which happens very rarely, normally it runs at 30-35 Amps).  My client is asking me to feed this equipment from two separate breakers for redundancy (A little paranoid), so to try pleasing him I'm thinking about paralleling two breakers to feed the equipment.  Of course, EACH breaker I'm planing on installing in parallel is a 2x80 Amp Breaker running AWG # 2 cables for each breaker (95 Amps @ 60°C ) so I do not have the issue if one breaker trips the other one takes all the load and is not designed for it, nor does the cable.

My question is, is it correct to do this?  I have no other way to "Redundantly" feed the equipment.  And I'm guessing that if for any reason one breaker trips or is turned off intentionally, the other will still feed the load and is designed to carry all the current.

Of course I understand that I have to be careful that I "parallel" the phases correctly to avoid a short (L1 with L1 and L2 with L2).

Thanks

Comment: What is this piece of equipment?

Comment: Ok you must not understand how breakers work. Did you know that a single breaker can maintain a value 3-8 times it's rated value based on the time the high current load? Now you are even thinking about this tells me you should not be doing this work, ok you size the wiring to each of the 2 breakers one trips one dosenot , guess what read hot wires start a fire. I think this is like 2 donkeys pulling 1 cart, they are the same age and similar size but one is stronger than the other, in this case you only go in circles. With power you wake up or not to a fire!

Comment: Neither case you mention is grounds for redundancy.  If the breaker trips, it tripped for a reason. It needs to be off.  If the breaker is intentionally turned off, it needs to be off.   If the breaker is tripping and you’re trying to avoid that there is another problem you should be solving.

Comment: Reminder that voting indicates perceived value to the community, not your approval of solution ideas posed in the question. In this case, there's certainly value in the responses.

Comment: +1 Because you sought advice before doing such a thing.

Comment: When people talk about "redundancy" they typically mean in the context of safety or reliability.  As many others have said, this certainly doesn't increase your safety.  It doesn't help your reliability either - you would now have two devices that could fail instead of one.  Maybe you could start with what your trying to accomplish and we could help you find a solution.

Comment: DV'ers: The *question* is a fine one.  Any *answer* in the affirmative would be completely moronic, so definitely DV any such answer. **DVs are not answers**, if the answer is "no" write an answer that says "no". Remeber frame challenges are legal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.  Now that I read them I certainly can see the error of my thinking and other aspects of the lack of safety of that installation that I was not seeing yesterday.  I will tell my client that if he wants redundancy, he should stop being so cheap and buy an equipment with redundant Power supplies so I can run two separate AC installations to it and avoid any complications.

Answer (score 5):

You do not want to do this. Never even think of such a thing.

You could have an overload on the circuit that draws a lot of current that seriously overloads the wiring but those two high rated breakers may just happily split the load and not even trip. But yet the wire gets so hot that it starts to melt insulation, smolder and even break out into flame.

The only possible theory, however misguided it is, for paralleling breakers would be as some type of convenience factor in case one of the breakers trips. However breakers are meant for safety and any redundancy should speak to increased safety. This would lead to something more like series circuit breakers so that there would be a better chance that one would trip even if the other one has failed in the permanent ON condition.

Answer (score 3):

### First and foremost:  Bad Idea

Electrical systems are no place to get creative, even if there's no specific code article that forbids the non-standard, "creative" solution.

Fortunately there usually is a code article to make it an officially bad idea.  Paralleling as described is in violation of the National Elecrical Code, article 240.8:

> Fuses or Circuit Breakers in Parallel. Fuses and
>   circuit breakers shall be permitted to be connected in parallel where they are factory assembled in parallel and listed
>   as a unit. Individual fuses, circuit breakers, or combinations
>   thereof shall not otherwise be connected in parallel.

If you cobble something together to combine two receptacles, that would violate the listing of the hardware, also a violation.

You'd also be over-supplying the equipment - that is, you can't supply equipment listed for 60A with 120A of power, you could dangerously overload the internals of the equipment, and violating the listing.

### Benefit - Doubtful

You might be able to put something compliant together with a transfer switch or with shunt-trip breakers or a contactor, but I think this is probably pointless.  With a dedicated circuit for the equipment, it sounds like an overload is unlikely to trip the breaker;  if there's a short that immediately trips the breaker, it would trip both breakers.  If someone turns off one breaker, they very well might turn off both.

### Alternatives

To prevent someone from unintentionally turning off the breaker, you can install a lock that holds it in the ON position.  This may sound unsafe, but breakers are designed to trip internally even with the handle locked in the ON position.  Some emergency circuits are actually required to be locked on.

It is possible to have UPS systems built that are fed by multiple circuits.  The design must be reviewed and stamped by an electrical engineer and UL must come out to inspect and list the custom equipment.  This won't be cheap or easy.  However a UPS can sound an alarm when the power is lost, and can supply power until power is restored.

Answer (score 2):

### Frame Challenge: He's barking up the wrong tree

He is worried about redundancy. The fact is, these things almost never fail.  And by adding complexity, **he's actually making things less reliable**. So really, he needs to install one *quality* unit and do what is necessary to make that easy to readily fix.

Now, if he's got a special situation where, say, his wires are vulnerable to physical damage or something, the spirit of Code says "Then, increase the protection on the wires".  However, he should run them on different routes, *which would preclude paralleling* as paralleled wires must be exactly the same length.

### Different routes and interlocking

What he can do is have, on the *delivery* side, a *main-lug* subpanel fitted with a generator interlock kit, and backfeed the whole kaboodle. Each of the 2-pole breakers is supplied by a different supply circuit from the main panel.

[image]

These breakers are back-fed, so they must be tied down, but many interlock kits take care of that for you.  Anyway, this is exactly how you'd interlock a generator.  Just the two sources are coming from the same place.  This is legit.

Now to avoid having a third breaker in the sub to supply the load, I would just feed it off the panel's main lugs.  For style points, mount it upside-down so they appear like feedthru lugs with two main breakers.

**Heck, you can even use this approach to serve the load from different panels *or even services***. However, if you do that, you MUST switch the neutral (assuming there is a neutral) which means the pictured item won't do.  They make similar interlocks for 3-phase panels, and you can just use one of those and treat neutral like a phase. If there's no neutral, nevermind.

But you see, we've added complexity; there are now four breakers involved: 2 in the main panel and 2 in this interlocked sub. Any 1 breaker failing is a condition he can ride through; however if 2 breakers fail the circuit fails.  If he need live, real-time, automatic ridethrough, substitute an ATS intended for a generator. But again, *more complexity*.

### You still need a shutoff near the machine, remember

Don't forget the Code that says any hardwired machine needs a shutoff switch **within sight of the machine**. As such, the generator interlock approach *makes a lot of sense*, because it provides that as a side-effect.

You need visual-range shutoff because otherwise you get this scenario.  Engineering goes to service Machine X on floor 3, so they stop at floor 1 to shut off the breaker.  Simultaneously, Goober goes to use Machine X, and finds it abruptly shuts off as he starts it.  So Goober goes down to floor 1 to reset the breaker.  He passes Engineering on the stairway, no words spoken.

### Parallel, with better wire *and* special gear

I like to think you're getting downvotes because people are inferring that you intend to use #2 *copper*.  Nobody should be using copper at such large sizes; you should be using **aluminum** and that necessitates a *2 numerical size* "bump", which is to #0 also called 1/0.  **And Voila. At 1/0 or larger, Voila! [The paralleling rules](https://www.ecmag.com/section/systems/conductors-connected-parallel) kick in**.

To start with, you can not just hack-a-dack a couple of 80A breakers into a regular panel.  You will need to have a single 80A breaker feeding **special equipment that is designed specifically to do paralleling** on the supply end. I'm not sure you'll find any such equipment sized for 80A / 1/0 wire; nobody in their right mind would parallel at such a low ampacity, they would just use bigger wire.

So you would need to use special equipment made for paralleling which would have the correct fusing within it.  Like I say, this tend to be made for bigger equipment, so it will be ex.pen.sive.

By the way, paralleling does make sense at a point (larger than 1/0).  You may notice that [wire capacity](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/) is *not* proportional to area cross-section.  *It is more proportional to wire surface*.  Because the limiting factor is the wire's ability to shed heat, i.e. its surface area.  It is a victim of the square-cube law; quadrupling cross section only doubles surface area.  As a result, at large sizes you hit a wall where increasing diameter uses a great deal of copper for a limited gain in surface area.  That happens before you hit the largest possible wire (e.g. 2000 kcmil).  So you might be better off running four 250 kcmil lines (205A x 4) instead of one 1000 kcmil (445A).  But *laugh* at #2, you're not anywhere near this.

Comment: I completely agree with you.  the Amperage is too low for anything so complex, and the price of the equipment is even lower.  If my client wants redundancy, he should stop being cheap and purchase the dual Power Supply option on the equipment side and avoid all this.  Thanks for your very detailed explanation I will certainly take it into consideration for other type of projects.

Comment: @Ronald actually, thank *you* for making me think it.  I have an industrial building where we prefer to keep the 480V service shut off.  However, we need some lights in the dark building to *guide you* to the switch.  I was going to tap the feed side of the main switch with a separate fuse block to a small transformer, which is sketchy. Now, I will use the "gen interlock" method to use 2 services, one past the switch and the other brought over from a small building nearby.